# appengine php file uploads fails with 500

Tags: php, google-app-engine, upload

Having a problem using php55 on GAE to upload files.  i have a working project that I moved to a new region.  however, the new project, every time I submit a file for upload, I get: Error: Server Error // The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. // Please try again in 30 seconds.

Log shows:

```
POST /programs/document_upload.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0" "[removed by me].appspot.com" ms=71 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117ce8c499c97d89f7cb939b5bef3572160133de2db952aa263e080a86878f5c24be90b6 app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=-
```

and

```
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)
```

The php file loads fine and then posts to itself to upload the file, which is where it dies.  here's the relevant code:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
    {
    if(is_array($_FILES['file']['name'])) 
        {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++) 
            {
            if($_FILES['file']['size'][$i]==0) continue;
            $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]=str_replace('.jpeg','.jpg',$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);    // convert file extension name of jpeg to jpg
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],"gs://[removed by me].appspot.com/pmd-scans/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]); 
            }
        }
    }
?>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<FORM name=form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data">
<INPUT type=file name='file[]' multiple accept='image/jpg'> <INPUT type=submit value='Upload'>
</BODY></HTML>
```

app.yaml has:

```
version: 4 
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
```

The folder exists in cloud storage.  Is there some setting in GAE that i'm forgetting to enable for php file uploads?

Comment: You mentioned that you have moved your GAE project to a new region. I suppose you had to create a new project for this. Did you also create a new bucket in Google Cloud Storage? My first guess would be that either the new app has not the Google Cloude Storage API turned on (in that case compare the API settings between old and new project) or the new app has no permission to write/read into the (old?) bucket.

Comment: Have you checked the Logging in Cloud Console for this error request? Maybe there are more details that will help you to understand the root of the issue.

Comment: yes, its a new project with its on GCS buckets.  i can read from the GCS buckets, but maybe it is a write-permission problem.  I'll see if I can look further into it.  I checked the GCS bucket log under Logging but found nothing.  is there somewhere else to look?

Comment: I think it has to do with the POST handler.  If the problem was in php or php's access to the buckets, i ought to get a php error in the log instead of dying with the 500 error.   but i don't know where to look next.

Comment: Addl info:  i did a test by going back to the original project and altering the code so that the file upload would save to a bucket in the new project; i also added the old service to the new project.  file upload worked fine, so there's something about the new project's setup that it fails on the POST handler.  maybe it thinks it isn't php55 even though it says that in the app.yaml file?

Comment: I think you need to look into the log of the GAE app, not the GCS bucket. In case you are not very familiar with the Logging: In Cloud Console, click on Logging for your affected new project, then at the filters on top of the list, select "GAE Application" and the affected service (or "All module_id") and in the other drop-downs "request_log" and "Error". That should show you a list of requests with an error and the path that was requested. Expand the one you are looking for and hopefully the details will give you a hint.

Comment: If you just copied your entire app code-base including the app.yaml file, I don't think the app.yaml file is the problem (unless you have specified "application: " in it). One more idea: you could do a side-by-side comparison of your two projects' "API & Services"? In the dashboard page you should see a table with all enabled APIs of the project... at least the Cloud Storage APIs should be enabled for both. If I remember correctly, they are turned on by default if you deploy a GAE app, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes, i did.  well, as quickly as it stopped working, it started working again.  only change i can point to is that i added a 'phpversion' command to verify php was at 5.5 (it was) and reloaded the file.  thanks for all your help!